# Inflection point

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I want to sketch the graph of

$$ y = 0.768x - 0.00004x^3 $$

I have found the critical points

1. Min. $(-80, -40\frac{24}{25} )$
2. Max. $(80, 40\frac{24}{25} )$

However , I do not know where does the min/max points start to turn (inflection points) how do I find that ?

Comment: Inflection points are roots of $y''$, and the lowest-order ($\geq 3$) non-zero derivative of $y$ must be of odd order (unless you group inflection and undulation points together).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An inflection point is a point on a curve at which the sign of the curvature (i.e., the concavity) changes

$$ y = 0.768x - 0.00004x^3 $$

$$ y' = 0.768 - 0.00004(3)x^2 $$

$$ y^{''} = -0.00004(3)(2)x $$

Can you see at which point does $y^{"}$ changes sign?